# In spring batch processor wait one process to finish handler all data then execute next process

Tags: spring-batch

In the process of using spring batch, I have a requirement to read the excel file, complete the statistics of one of the columns, and then use the value of one of the columns divided by the statistical result.Examples are as follows

```
input:
name price
a 10
b 20
c 30

ouput:
name price proportion
a 10 1/6
b 20 1/3
c 30 1/2
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to go with two steps :

1. The first one (tasklet) who calculate the sum of all the prices and register the result in the jobExecutionContext
2. And the second one (chunk) to re read the file and write the proportion column with the sum calculated in the first step.

Comment: Is there no other better solution than the one you suggested? The first thing I think of is to use the solution you said, but I think this solution is not the optimal solution. Because each step requires raw data, read the file twice or cache the data in the first step. What I want is to use CompositeItemProcessor to process all the data in the first Processor and then to the next Processor, so that I don't have to read the file twice or cache the data. But what I know is that CompositeItemProcessor is not like this. Every time data processing passes through all the processors.